# How do I make video tutorials of someone(s) working through a website on their computer?

Tags: video-editor, video-recording, webvideos

The trivial way to solve this problem is just to screen record my computer, but I want it to look professional.

I don't want unprescribed mouse movements. I want them to be direct and towards the object they are clicking on. I want to have transitions and maybe an auto-generated voice over?

I'm really really new to this so please forgive me if this answer has been asked or is obvious...

Is there any software that people generally use for this that is relatively affordable and appropriate for a novice. Any kind of software is fine for me. I'm just new to video editing and creation. Software that has built in functionality targeted at this problem would be very helpful, almost like a wizard of sorts.

I want to create a video tutorial of a user using my website.

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camtasia is probably the leading software for creating video tutorials, it has the ability to [smooth mouse movements](https://youtu.be/UIMZ60-u0bM), the editor gives you the ability to add text, transitions and other effects as well.

The software is quite expensive. It has a free trial for 30 days, however videos exported will have watermarks.

If you already have access to video editing software, you may be able to reproduce the same effect setting keyframes for start and end positions of a mouse cursor graphic and animating between those two points. You would need use screen recording software that hides the cursor as you will be using your own graphic of a cursor.

Comment: That's relatively affordable for a single license, and exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for. Ty!